# Search Behaves Different Depending on How Application Exited

Tags: android, search

I add my application to my phone's search:

[image]

If I "Home" out of the application and utilize the search above, then the search opens the results within my application (it's a weather application).

If I "Back" out of the application, then the search does not go into my application.

I understand that "Home" pauses, and "Back" destroys, but is there a way to handle this so that if using this functionality that my application will open?